# Chrome & Angular 7: flashes of unstyled content on redraw if css imported via sanitizer

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome, webfonts

I built an app which imports a user-created stylesheet. In this file a locally saved font is referenced. The css-file is imported via the DOMSanitizer function `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("resources/custom-styles.css")`. This works generally as expected; especially with the latest Firefox browser.

Chrome (v.71) though reverts to the fallback font frequently just to replace it milliseconds later. This seems to happen everytime a mouseEvent is processed (i.e. mouse move, click,...). All processed mouse events have `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` in common - which I can not imagine to be the culprit.

In a previous version I statically imported the font (`@Import url`...) which worked well in both browsers.

`custom-styles.css`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: customFont;
  font-display: auto;
  src: local('customFont'), url(fonts/customFont.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

`.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" [href]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("resources/custom-styles.css")'>

<div>
  <span style="font-family: customFont">My Font</span>
</div>
```

`.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  // title = 'app';   

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

What can I change to make Chrome behaving like Firefox?